# (BloC) StreamBuilder alway is !snapshot.hasData

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

I learning BloC design pattern for Flutter.

This is my tutorial https://medium.com/flutterpub/architecting-your-flutter-project-bd04e144a8f1

My problem is `snapshot.data` in `StreamBuilder` alway is null.

This is my SlideModel:

```
class SlideModel {
  Widget dot;
  String urlImage, name;

  SlideModel(this.dot, this.urlImage, this.name);
}
```

This is my Provider:

```
class SlideProvider {
  List<SlideModel> getList() {
    List<SlideModel> listSlide = List<SlideModel>();

    listSlide.add(SlideModel(
        Dots.dot(Colors.black54), 'https://i.imgur.com/c7Uvh6h.jpg', 'A'));
    listSlide.add(SlideModel(
        Dots.dot(Colors.black54),
        'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0810/8331/files/category_banner_ip8.jpg?1347021331059137510',
        'B'));
    listSlide.add(SlideModel(
        Dots.dot(Colors.black54), 'https://i.imgur.com/gAumC4V.jpg', 'C'));
    listSlide.add(SlideModel(
        Dots.dot(Colors.black54), 'https://i.imgur.com/n7g3Naf.jpg', 'D'));

    return listSlide;
  }
}
```

This is my Repository:

```
class Repository {
  SlideProvider _slideProvider = SlideProvider();

  List<SlideModel> getAllSlide() {
    return _slideProvider.getList();
  }
}
```

SlideBloc:

```
class SlideBloc {
  Repository _repository = Repository();
  final _streamController = PublishSubject<List<SlideModel>>();

  Observable<List<SlideModel>> stream() {
    return _streamController.stream;
  }

  getAllSlide() {
    List<SlideModel> slides = _repository.getAllSlide();
    _streamController.sink.add(slides);
  }

  dispose(){
    _streamController.close();
  }
}

final slideBloc = SlideBloc();
```

This is my UI Widget, alway print "No data".
I want to fix it:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    slideBloc.getAllSlide();
    // TODO: implement build
      return StreamBuilder(
      stream: slideBloc.stream(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasError) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return slideShow(snapshot.data);
          } else {
            print('No data');
            return Text('No Data');
          }
        } else {
          print(snapshot.error);
          return Text(snapshot.error);
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it may have to do with

```
getAllSlide() {
    List<SlideModel> slides = _repository.getAllSlide();
    _streamController.sink.add(slides);
  }
```

inside of your slideBloc file.

Try making it like this:

```
fetchAllMovies() async {
    ItemModel itemModel = await _repository.fetchAllMovies();
    _moviesFetcher.sink.add(itemModel);
  }
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: np, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

When working with `StreamBuilder` widget you can use a **StreamController**, as follow.

```
class SlideBloc {
  Repository _repository = Repository();
  final _streamController = StreamController<List<SlideModel>>();

  Stream<List<SlideModel>> stream() {
    return _streamController.stream;
  }

  getAllSlide() {
    List<SlideModel> slides = _repository.getAllSlide();
    _streamController.sink.add(slides);
  }

  dispose(){
    _streamController.close();
  }
}

final slideBloc = SlideBloc();
```

In your UI you can specify the expected Model, see:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    slideBloc.getAllSlide();
    return StreamBuilder<List<SlideModel>>(
      stream: slideBloc.stream(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasError) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            print(snapshot.data.first.name);
            return Text('Has DATA');
          } else {
            print('No data');
            return Text('No Data');
          }
        } else {
          print(snapshot.error);
          return Text(snapshot.error);
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

This is one way to solve it. Hope this help.